# how can I convert position (2nd, 3rd or 4th etc ) to index(00 for 1st position, 01 for 2nd etc) in 2D array in python numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

```
    import numpy as np;
entries = [];
# take user input
row = int(input("Enter number of rows: "));
column = int(input("Enter number of columns: "));

print("Enter Values");
# get values
for i in range(row):
    a = [];
    for j in range(column):
        a.append(int(input()));
    entries.append(a);

#  convert values into matrix (dimentional array)
matrix = np.array(entries).reshape(row, column);

print("Matrix is :");
print(matrix);
```

I want to know the logic so if user enter that he wants to change the element on nth position, how to change that position to index to perform update operation?

Let say with above code user creates this array

```
    [[10 24 32
[45 56 62]]
```

and after that he want to change the 4th position element just by entering position... how to convert that position into index?

Comment: I think you want a tuple of row, col = `((pos-1) // matrix.shape[1], (pos-1) % matrix.shape[1])`? So if the user enters 4, you get the 1st row and 0th column

Comment: Questions are better if they start with sample variables and arrays, such as `row`, `column` and `entries`.  That use `input` stuff is isn't easy to copy-n-paste (can't copy the 'user'!), and isn't important to the update operation.  The [mcve] link might help.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. I don't see difference between `n-th position` and `index` - your description maybe suggest only `index = pos - 1`. OR maybe you want to convert position to pairs of indexes `(row,col)` (or `(y,x)`) then you whould need `divide and modulo` something like `y = pos // len(row)`, `x = pos % len(row)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with simple maths:

```py
import numpy as np

x = [[10 ,24 ,32],
[45 ,56 ,62]]

x = np.array(x)
pos, val = 4, -1
x[pos//x.shape[1], pos%x.shape[0]] = val
```

Outputs:

```py
[[10 24 32]
 [-1 56 62]]
```